# UITableViewCell issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am added uitextfield into uitableviewcell using this code

textField=[[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 290, 70)]autorelease]; textField.delegate=self; textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeURL; textField.autocorrectionType=YES; textField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor]; textField.placeholder=@"Enter feed url"; [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

When i click the textField the keyboard will appear...But While i am editing text in the textField the magnifying class should not work

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @OakBytes, if you're editing a post, try to fix everything. The code in this question is a total mess.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do this on the iphone or the simulator. I believe that on the simulator you need to right click to get the magnifying glass to appear. I know most mac mice only have one button but you need to do the equivalent. My mac has a pc mouse so I usually right click to get the magnifier up. Let me know if that helps.